# removing the ' ' and the spaces in the return output python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying out a function where you have to use `def function(a,b,c,d)`
a is a string so i did

```
a = str(a)
```

b is an integer so i did

```
b= int(b)
```

c is also a string;

```
c = str(c)
```

and d is a boolean (all i know about boolean is True or False); so

```
d = True
```

i wanted to change the order of the elements into

```
[c,a,b,d]
```

and i assigned this to `result = [c,a,b,d]`
when i used the return function

```
return str(result), (because i want to return a string)
```

i ended up with

```
"[ 'c', 'a', b, d]"
```

i have tried everything to get rid of the ' ' and also the spacing because it should really look like

```
'[c,a,b,d]'
```

what can i do to remove it?

```
def elem(tree,year,ident,passed):
    tree = str(tree)
    year = int(year)
    ident = str(ident)
    passed = True
    result = [ident,tree,year,passed]
    return str(result)
```

this is what i;ve done so far

so if i wanted to test the code i have so far in the python shell i end up with

```
>>> elem("pine",2013,"1357",True)
"['1357', 'pine', 2013, True]"
```

the output that i want from this is 
    '[1357,pine,2013,True]'

sorry if i didn't provide enough. this is all i have right now.. and sorry for not doing good formatting for the posting..

Comment: i also tried putting the " " inside and outside the brackets like "[" but obviously that did not help..

Comment: Can you provide an actual code snippet?

Comment: what is a code snippet?

Comment: I mean that you ought to post the entire function definition and how the function is being called, as one block of code. As it is, it's unclear exactly how you're calling the function and what you're doing in the function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because i don't think it is necessary to have the spaces and quotes inside the bracket for the output

Comment: _"test the code i have so far in the python shell i end up with"_ - great, now show us the output you _want_ from that evaluation as well

Comment: It is necessary - consider `elem('extra,pine',2013,"1357",True)` and `elem('pine',2013,"1357,extra",True)`, both of which you want to return `"[1357,extra,pine,2013,True]"` - they've become ambigious

Comment: @oyth94: spaces and quotes conform to the Python style, PEP008, something you should become familiar with if you are going to use python: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: so i finally got the expected output; i ended up with the typeerror saying that it cant convert int to string, and it cant convert boolean to string, but i got that all sorted out. thank you all for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just create the string you want from the data structure you have:

```
>>> '[{},{},{},{}]'.format('c','a',2,True) 
'[c,a,2,True]'
>>> '[{},{},{},{}]'.format(*['c','a',2,True])
'[c,a,2,True]'
>>> '[{},{},{},{}]'.format(*['1357', 'pine', 2013, True])
'[1357,pine,2013,True]'
```

Or edit the string representation of a data structure to be what you want it to be:

```
>>> str(['c', 'a', 2, True])
"['c', 'a', 2, True]"
>>> str(['c', 'a', 2, True]).replace("'","").replace(' ','')
'[c,a,2,True]'
```

In either case, the final outer `'` go away when you print the string:

```
>>> print('[{},{},{},{}]'.format(*['c','a',2,True]))
[c,a,2,True]
>>> print(str(['c', 'a', 2, True]).replace("'","").replace(' ',''))
[c,a,2,True]
>>> li=['1357', 'pine', 2013, True]
>>> print('[{},{},{},{}]'.format(*li))
[1357,pine,2013,True]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have `" "` is because it's a string. You returned the string representation of the list, when infact you should just be returning the list:

```
return result
```

With the string you have, you can safely convert it back to a list with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
...
myresult = function(a, b, c, d)
print ast.literal_eval(myresult)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return "[" + ",".join(result) + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `str(result)` it gives a string representation of the object `result`.  What that string actually looks like depends on the implementation of the class that the object belongs to (it calls the special method `__str__` in the class to do the conversion).

Since the object (`result`) belongs to class `list` then you get the standard string representation for a `list`.  You cannot (sensibly) change the `list` class, so you need to create a different representation.

In your sample code, I'm puzzled why you are doing the conversions.  Why convert `year` to an `int` when you want a string representation?  Why set `passed` to `True` when it is a parameter?  Anyway:

```
def elem(tree, year, ident, passed): 
    passed = True 
    result = "[%s,%s,%d,%s]" % (ident, tree, year, passed)  
    return result

print(elem("pine", 2013, "1357", True))
```

Gives:

```
[1357,pine,2013,True]
```

Comment: I haven't learned lists yet. I am a beginner in python so please forgive my lack of understanding.. I am trying not to use the print and input function for this though. is that possible?
I also don't understand what you did in your 
result = "[%s,%s,%d,%s]" % (ident, tree, year, passed). what does the first half mean (%s,%s,%d,%s) ?

Comment: @oyth94:  OK, you haven't learnt lists yet, but it was you that was using a list, not me.  The `print` statement is just to show what the output would look like.  I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with this.  The first half, `(%s,%s,%d,%s)` means I want to display the values as strings (%s) and digits (%d).

Comment: oh i was putting them as parameters... so the function has 4 parameters

Comment: @oyth94: Sorry, I'm not with you, why would that necessarily involve a list?

Comment: i didn't mean to put it as a list.. i don't even know how to put it as a list.. so if this is interpreted as a list to you, then the code i typed must have gone all wrong!